# Regex to retrieve a verification token from header

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have some head information from which I would like to extract the "RequestVerificationToken" value associated with the id ="LoginToken".

So in sample below I am after the value starting with "kL5Ukn...".

```
<span id="loginToken"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="kL5UknRMXsBy5QUMtDFPuBwESd89jK5l1VyF7SliGL8g0NCE-pnbowPMPtEMpi2Nmm9F_626FN-cQ6-miwS-CXXkQUM1" /></span>

<span id="registerToken"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="JDJD9khCZNjXeFGLMcBbqDqNmgR19Z-wy4FueH1CkWCdQQry_cgnKHLuj7uyrquk_gzDotKxN1ZQO8rPEc3fsH21uXc1" /></span>
```

Thanks

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: Ah sorry, I've updated the tag. This is using JMeter and its regular expression extractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `id="loginToken".*?value="(.*?)"`

and retrieve Group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B06YnY/1)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) as regular expressions are:

- hard to develop and maintain
- hard to read
- fragile and sensitive to markup changes as attributes position change or a new line will ruin your script while the response will still be a valid HTML

So I would recommend going for [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead, the relevant configuration would be:

- Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
- CSS/JQuery expression: `span[id=loginToken] > input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]`
- Attribute: `value`

Other settings may be left intact.

Demo:

[image: JMeter CSS/JQuery Extractor Demo]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I wasn't even aware JMeter had a JQuery extractor.